Avoid autoindent when using code action e.g., extract to field in VSCode
I'm using VSCode to write a Java project. Using the refactor features e.g., extract to field or method worked fine before. However, now, every time I use the feature, the added line and everything after it are auto-indented. I tried tweaking the indent settings on my editor, but I've only managed to stop it for extract to method. extract to field, etc. is still the same.


Try open your settings (File > Preferences > Settings), then navigate to "Editor" and set the "editor.autoIndent" setting to "none"

I tried this, but it only disabled autoindent on code that I write myself,  and did not work for the issue I mentioned. I only want it disabled on new lines of code added by refactoring features.
